# Why in Google Cloud (GCP), Cloud Run and Cloud Function needs Serverless VPC access/connector to access VPC but Cloud Compute VM does not?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

In Google Cloud (GCP), there are two convenient serverless deployment services: Cloud Run and Cloud Functions.

Alternatively, there is Cloud Compute, which is just a VM. It is not serverless.

When I provision a Cloud Compute VM, I can specify a VPC to which this VM belongs. That's it. VPC here is just the configuration of the networking.

In contrast, for Cloud Run and Cloud Function, I need to have Serverless VPC access/connector, which Cloud Run or Function uses to access a VPC, which that Connector points to.

The Serverless VPC access/connector is not just a network stack configuration; it is a running VM.

What is so fundamentally different between the Cloud Compute VM and Cloud Run/Function?

The documentation and tutorials usually explain how to configure the Serverless VPC access/connector or its use cases, but I struggle to find the explanation of why this concept of the Serverless VPC access/connector exists in the first place,

Answer (score 1):

When you create a VM you attach the network interface to your VPC.

When you go serverless, you don't have to worry about the computing unit and the network configuration. All these stuff run in a Google managed project, the serverless world.

Therefore, because the resource lives outside, you need a bridge between the serverless world and your own VPC. A serverless VPC connector. And yes, this connector is simply a cluster of machine that bridge the network traffic.

However, with Cloud Run, something new happen: Direct VPC access. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/vpc-direct-vpc

No extra VM but other limitations/constraint!

Comment: Just curious but would not the google server hosting the "serverless" project, in fact, be a server?

Comment: @easleyfixed - not a server, but a cluster of servers. Internet search for "Google Borg". https://research.google/pubs/large-scale-cluster-management-at-google-with-borg/

Comment: So the plurization of the term serverless, by nature, being more than one server in a cluster,  therefor makes it serverless?  Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Serverless (or managed) term describe an operational model. There are always servers somewhere, but not managed by you, by someone else. On your side it's serverless, you worry only about the code, not the infra